# Iterating over a list of array objects (trying to make code more concise)

Tags: java, list, loops, iteration, code-duplication

I currently have the following code:

```
if (task5.isVisible()) {
    if (!task1.isVisible()) {
        task1.setVisible(true);
        checkBox1.setVisible(true);
    } else if (!task2.isVisible()) {
        task2.setVisible(true);
        checkBox2.setVisible(true);
    } else if (!task3.isVisible()) {
        task3.setVisible(true);
        checkBox3.setVisible(true);
    } else if (!task4.isVisible()) {
        task4.setVisible(true);
        checkBox4.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        task6.setVisible(true);
        checkBox6.setVisible(true);
    }
} else if (task4.isVisible()) {
    if (!task1.isVisible()) {
        task1.setVisible(true);
        checkBox1.setVisible(true);
    } else if (!task2.isVisible()) {
        task2.setVisible(true);
        checkBox2.setVisible(true);
    } else if (!task3.isVisible()) {
        task3.setVisible(true);
        checkBox3.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        task5.setVisible(true);
        checkBox5.setVisible(true);
    }
} else if (task3.isVisible()) {
    if (!task1.isVisible()) {
        task1.setVisible(true);
        checkBox1.setVisible(true);
    } else if (!task2.isVisible()) {
        task2.setVisible(true);
        checkBox2.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        task4.setVisible(true);
        checkBox4.setVisible(true);
    }
} else if (task2.isVisible()) {
    if (!task1.isVisible()) {
        task1.setVisible(true);
        checkBox1.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        task3.setVisible(true);
        checkBox3.setVisible(true);
    }
} else if (task1.isVisible()) {
    task2.setVisible(true);
    checkBox2.setVisible(true);
} else {
    task1.setVisible(true);
    checkBox1.setVisible(true);
}
```

and am trying to make it more concise using loops, lists and maps. I created an ArrayList that takes TextField array objects and a HashMap that takes TextFields as keys and CheckBoxes as values.

```
private List<TextField[]> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
private Map<TextField, CheckBox> map = new HashMap<>();

tasks.add(new TextField[]{task5, task6, task1, task2, task3, task4});
tasks.add(new TextField[]{task4, task5, task1, task2, task3});
tasks.add(new TextField[]{task3, task4, task1, task2});
tasks.add(new TextField[]{task2, task3, task1});
tasks.add(new TextField[]{task1, task2, task1});

map.put(task1, checkBox1);
map.put(task2, checkBox2);
map.put(task3, checkBox3);
map.put(task4, checkBox4);
map.put(task5, checkBox5);
map.put(task6, checkBox6);
```

I've tried doing the following:

```
for (TextField[] task : tasks) {
    if (task[0].isVisible()) {
        for (int i = 2; i < task.length; i++) {
            if (!task[i].isVisible()) {
                task[i].setVisible(true);
                map.get(task[i]).setVisible(true);
                break;
            } else {
                task[1].setVisible(true);
                map.get(task[1]).setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (task[0] == task1) {
            task1.setVisible(true);
            checkBox1.setVisible(true);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It's almost the same but there seem to be a couple mismatches. I've tried using the debugger, but it doesn't serve to be quite useful when dealing with JavaFX. Any help/attempt at fixing my problem would be greatly appreciated.

In summary, I just need to make the code at the top of the page (the one with tons of if, else if and else statements) more concise.

The full code is available at https://github.com/KrishMehta/ToDo (it's a JavaFX project btw)

Comment: the logic is unclear. why does `task4.isVisible()` not check `task6`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I'm making a ToDo app, and I want it so if you click the plus button then it should make the TextField (task) visible. I only want it to add one at a time. I also have it so that if someone clicks the checkmark (when the task is visible) then the task goes invisible. What I want to do is make it so that it checks if every TextField is there or not, and if a TextField before the current iteration (so like check TextField #1 at iteration #3, and if TextField is not there, then it should make that visible instead of TextField #4 - even if TextField #2 or #3 is visible)

Comment: If that doesn't make sense, then maybe this will help:

This is what I want: https://gyazo.com/6ff2f8fa1ae757848edb62ff1a998844 (works with all the if, else if and else statements)

And this is what is currently happening with the for loop: https://gyazo.com/c5a18a4d1cd15f154650ad5f65db5396

Comment: You need to describe what you are trying to achieve in the question. Refactoring that big snippet may lead to writing another messy one. You need to solve the main problem that causes that snippet to appear. The names are very obscure, btw.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I've linked the project at the bottom of my post. I would really appreciate if you could help me out at making this code more concise.

Comment: If you want to create a ToDo app, I don't understand why you prepare for exactly 6 tasks. I'd expect an unlimited-number approach using a list of tasks. And it looks like you're not separating model, view and controller which is generally highly recommended.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I am separating them? Check my code at @ https://github.com/KrishMehta/ToDo. Also, it's a simple project that's only supposed to take ~1 day to complete, so 6 tasks is good. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: There's nothing in your model package describing which Tasks the User still has to do, nor whether a given Task is completed or not, and the code you showed us seems to be from the AddItemController and to deal with exactly such changes, but without using anything from the model, just manipulating the view.

Comment: And 6 tasks is bad. It makes for a more complicated structure than going for variable-length from the beginning. As a rule of thumb, if you need more than two elements of some kind, arrange them in a List instead of individual variables.